# Changing page title background in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

On each page of my site, the page title is displayed, which is fine but the background is white, while the rest of the site is green. Is there a css code so I can change the background of the page titles? I have the Aeonblog theme which does not have the option to change it in page settings.

Furthermore, there is a bar below the menu showing the navigation (e.g., Home > blog) which is also in a different color, how can I change this?

Thanks so much

I tried some css codes already, but .header or .page_header did not work.

Comment: Hey @verhe!  Glad you joined the community! In this sort of circumstance, a couple images and/or links may assist people in seeing your problem; it can also catch someone's eyes better, i.e. less people will just leave the question, and you'll get more answers. Take care!